# Search missing numbers in sequence

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following array (my sequences are all sorted in ascending order, and contain positive integers)

```
var tabSequence = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 32 };
```

I made a code using LINQ and a loop to search missing numbers like that :

```
List<Int32> lstSearch = new List<int>();
var lstGroup = tabSequence
    .Select((val, ind) => new { val, group = val - ind })
    .GroupBy(v => v.group, v => v.val)
    .Select(group => new{ GroupNumber = group.Key, Min = group.Min(), Max = group.Max() }).ToList();

for (int number = 0; number < lstGroup.Count; number++)
{
    if (number < lstGroup.Count-1)
    {
        for (int missingNumber = lstGroup[number].Max+1; missingNumber < lstGroup[number+1].Min; missingNumber++) 
            lstSearch.Add(missingNumber);
    }               
}       
var tabSequence2 = lstSearch.ToArray();
// Same result as var tabSequence2 = new[] {4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 };
```

This code works but i'd like to know if there a better way to do the same thing only with linq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I am just not understanding the problem.  Your code seems very complicated, you could make this a lot simpler:

```
int[] tabSequence = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 32 };

var results = Enumerable.Range(1, tabSequence.Max()).Except(tabSequence);

//results is: 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 13, 14, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYD4um)

Comment: Darn, I just finished writing the same thing! :) Although I wrote `Enumerable.Range(tabSequence.Min(), tabSequence.Max() - tabSequence.Min() + 1)`

Comment: misunderstood the question :) nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IEnumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) to your advantage. The overload I choose uses an accumulator seed (empty `List<IEnumerable<int>>`) and proceeds to iterate over each item in your array.

The first time I set an `lastNR` defined before using the aggregate to the firsst number we iterate over. We compare the nexts iterations actual `nr` against this `lastNr`.

- If we are in sequence we just increment the `lastNr`.
- If not, we generate the missing numbers via [Enumerable.Range(a,count)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) between `lastNr`
  and the actual `nr` and add them to our accumulator-List. Then we set the `lastNr` to `nr` to continue.

---

```
public static List<IEnumerable<int>> GetMissingSeq(int[] seq)
{
    var lastNr = int.MinValue;
    var missing = seq.Aggregate(
        new List<IEnumerable<int>>(),
        (acc, nr) =>
        {
            if (lastNr == int.MinValue || lastNr == nr - 1)
            {
                lastNr = nr; // first ever or in sequence
                return acc;  // noting to do
            }

            // not in sequence, add the missing into our ac'umulator list
            acc.Add(Enumerable.Range(lastNr + 1, nr - lastNr - 1));
            lastNr = nr; //thats the new lastNR to compare against in the next iteration
            return acc;
        }
    );
    return missing;
}
```

Tested by:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tabSequence = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 32 };

    var lastNr = int.MinValue;
    var missing = tabSequence.Aggregate(
        new List<IEnumerable<int>>(),
        (acc, nr) =>
        {
            if (lastNr == int.MinValue || lastNr == nr - 1)
            {
                lastNr = nr; // first ever or in sequence
                return acc;  // noting to do
            }

            acc.Add(Enumerable.Range(lastNr + 1, nr - lastNr - 1));
            return acc;
        }
    );

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", tabSequence));

    foreach (var inner in GetMissingSeq(tabSequence))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", inner));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 22, 23, 32  // original followed by missing sequences
4, 5, 6
10, 11
13, 14
18, 19, 20, 21
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
```

If you are not interested in the subsequences you can use `GetMissingSeq(tabSequence).SelectMany(i => i)` to flatten them into one IEnumerable.

Comment: This code is useful too...I need to practice with such examples. Thanks !

Comment: @Fabrice76 Good - I misunderstood your question and thought you needed the sub-sequences so its much longer then needed. Did not like to delete it b/c of effort to write it ;) might help some other fellow out later on and with SelectMany() one _could_ (never should) use it to get'em'all. Feel free to upvote - once you get the needed rep, your adding to mine ;)